# How would I print out the perfect numbers along with their divisors shown next to them in python?

Tags: python, perfect-numbers

```
#I have the formula in which the code produces all perfect numbers between 1 and 10,000 and I want the divisors printed out alongside the perfect numbers 
n = 1

while n <= 10001:

    sum = 0
    divisor = 1
    while divisor < n:
        if not n % divisor:
            sum += divisor
        divisor = divisor + 1
    if sum == n:
        print(n, "is a perfect number")
    n = n + 1
#for example, I want the output to look like:
```

> 6 - proper divisors: 1, 2, 3

> 28 - proper divisors: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

Comment: You should return/yield `n` instead of incrementing counter

Comment: If you want to print the divisors, then you need to keep track of them in a list.  You're not doing that.  And technically, 6 is a proper divisor of 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't track the sum, track the divisors and check the sum at the end:

```
for n in range(1, 10001):
    divisors = []
    for divisor in range(1, n//2+1):
        if not n % divisor:
            divisors.append( divisor )
    if sum(divisors) == n:
        divisors.append( n )
        print(n, "is a perfect number", divisors)
```

Output:

```
6 is a perfect number [1, 2, 3, 6]
28 is a perfect number [1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 28]
496 is a perfect number [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 62, 124, 248, 496]
8128 is a perfect number [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 127, 254, 508, 1016, 2032, 4064, 8128]
```

Obligatory list comprehension solution:

```
for n in range(1, 10001):
    divisors = [divisor for divisor in range(1, n//2+1) if not n % divisor]
    if sum(divisors) == n:
        divisors.append( n )
        print(n, "is a perfect number", divisors)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the issue I was having.